# Is it ok to ask book recommendations on music/ piano on stack exchange?

Tags: discussion

I have been evaluating a few books but not being able to determine which is better. I am not sure if I can ask about them on stack exchange, because I have faced rather strong and rude reactions to a simple question once. So, I am wondering if it is ok to ask book recommendations on music/ piano on stack exchange?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78387/discussion-on-question-by-subir-nag-is-it-ok-to-ask-book-recommendations-on-musi).

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the help center, there is a page that says questions should **not** be about:

> - shopping help — including product or music search — or buying/selling advice or recommendations
> - recommendations of pieces to listen to, study, or play, or that meet particular criteria

Generally, the community has interpreted questions about book recommendations to be in one or both of the above categories, so a book recommendation question is off-topic.

One guideline might be that any question that asks, "Which one is good/better/best or bad/worse/worst?" is going to be off-topic. So asking "which of these books is the best?" or "Which of these books should I buy?" (almost the same question) is not a good question for this site.

Comment: What are your thoughts on questions along the lines of "is something like xxxx available?" rather than "is x better than y?"